# Filtering one column based on values in two other columns

Tags: python, filtering

I've got an upper boundary and a lower boundary based on a predicted value and I want to filter out the data that do not fall between the upper and lower boundaries.

My data frame looks like this

| weight KG | Upper Boundary | Lower Boundary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23.2 | 30 | 20 |
| 55.2 | 40 | 30 |
| 44.2 | 50 | 40 |
| 47.8 | 50 | 40 |
| 38.7 | 30 | 20 |

and I'd like it to look like this

| weight KG | Upper Boundary | Lower Boundary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23.2 | 30 | 20 |
| 44.2 | 50 | 40 |
| 47.8 | 50 | 40 |

I have tried this but it does not filter properly.
df2= df1[(df1['weight_KG'] <= df1["UpperBoundary"]) &  (df1['weight_KG'] >= df1["LowerBoundary"]]

Comment: Btw isn't your logic wrong?  (df1['weight_KG'] <= df1["LowerBoundary"])  this should be >= no?

Comment: I have implemented it as shown in you question and everything works fine. Where is the problem? Is it maybe the missing `)` before the last `]`?

Comment: Thanks! I wrote it incorrectly in the post by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. If it doesn't do the job. It might have the version and platform related thing.

My environment is following:

- Macbook M1 chip, Ventura
- Python 3.9.14
- Pandas 1.5.2

Code is following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Build DataFrame
names = ["weight_KG", "UpperBoundary", "LowerBoundary"]
weight_KG = [23.2, 55.2, 44.2, 47.8, 38.7, 0]
UpperBoundary = [30, 40, 50, 50, 30, 20]
LowerBoundary = [20, 30, 40, 40, 20, 10]

dict = {
    "weight_KG": weight_KG,
    "UpperBoundary": UpperBoundary,
    "LowerBoundary": LowerBoundary,
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df2 = df1[
    (df1["weight_KG"] <= df1["UpperBoundary"])
    & (df1["weight_KG"] >= df1["LowerBoundary"])
]
print(df2)
print(pd.__version__)
```

Output is following:

```
   weight_KG  UpperBoundary  LowerBoundary
0       23.2             30             20
2       44.2             50             40
3       47.8             50             40
1.5.2
```